Is it possible to perform quantization aware training on my Conv1d model?
I have found many questions online about neural networks with conv1d layers giving this error or similar errors when trying to do quantization aware training, but I haven't found a definitive solution or workaround.
Layer conv1d_28:<class 'tf_keras.src.layers.convolutional.conv1d.Conv1D'> is not supported. You can quantize this layer by passing a `tfmot.quantization.keras.QuantizeConfig` instance to the `quantize_annotate_layer` API.

Is it possible to apply quantization aware training on a network with conv1d layers in Keras?
